# ANTLR4: How to modify a token without tying the grammar to a particular target language?

Tags: parsing, antlr, token, antlr4, lexer

If the input string is this:

> 'hello'

I want the lexer to send up to the parser this token:

> "hello"

with token type STRING.

If the input string is this:

> "hello"

I want the lexer to send up to the parser this token:

> "hello"

with token type STRING.

That is, regardless of the string delimiter, I want the lexer to send up to the parser the token delimited with the double quote ( " ) and token type STRING.

And, I do not want to tie the grammar to a particular target language.

Is there a way to accomplish this in ANTLR4?

Comment: Does using a semantic predicate tie the grammar to Java?

Comment: Semantic predicates are expressed in a particular programming language and therefore semantic predicates are not an acceptable approach.

Comment: Using `-> type(STRING);` at the end of your lexer rule, you can specify the token type. However, for the `'`/`"` issue, no idea. Perhaps using grammar rule to match `SQUOTE ID SQUOTE` or `DQUOTE ID DQUOTE`... but you will lost STRING token type.

Comment: Using lexer modes to skip the quotes, you can send the unquoted contents of the string, leaving it to the parser to add the double quotes if it needs to. I don't know how to replace the single quote with a double quote without using language-specific code, but it's also not clear to me why you would want the parser to see the double quotes.

Comment: There are lots of real-world use cases where you want the lexer to make small tweaks to the token before it is sent up to the parser. My example is merely intended to illustrate such real-world problems in a simple, easy-to-understand manner. Plus I don't want the grammar tied to a particular programming language.